# How the sizeof() function works for Structures in C?

Tags: c, struct

The Structure is defined as follows

```
typedef struct Sample
{
  int test;
  char strtest;
} Sample;
```

In Main Function, I called Sizeof the structure.

```
sizeof(struct Sample)
```

I've heard the return value of sizeof on structures could be incorrect. If this is the case, what should I do to get the right value?

Comment: Without a typedef in scope `Sample` is not a valid type. Are you using a C++ compiler for C code? I suggest you don't do that ... and if `Sample` is an object the parenthesis are redundant.

Comment: sizeof is not a function, but a compiler directive.
It means it is not executed runtime, but it is replaced with the corresponding value at compile time.

Comment: It's never "incorrect".  Only your understanding is lacking, not the compiler.

Answer (score 22):

It does return a reliable value - just not always the value you expect.

In Sample structure, you are assuming a 1 byte char and 4 byte int, but you do not get a result of "5" .

Because the structure is padded so that elements start on their natural boundaries.
you are more likely to get a result of "8".

Wiki explains this pretty well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof - at "Structure Padding", near the bottom.

Comment: @ Karthik: Is it platform-independent ?

Comment: No, it's not platform independent; it's not even necessarily *compiler* independent.

Comment: @ Ernest : can u explain your thoughts

Comment: @user1093586: It is platform-*dependent*. Different platforms have different requirements on aliasing, so different amount of padding can be inserted. In fact, standard C does allows arbitrary padding to be inserted inside or at the end of a struct.

Comment: I didn't get any reputations for UpVotes.Why It happens?

Comment: To Whom I have to Ask in Stack Overflow Forum. Please anyone help on this.

Comment: @karthik It seems that you've reached daily reputation growth limit: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Comment: Yep, reputation cap. Commiserations. If I remember, I'll come back to upvote tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Sizeof is not a function; it is an *operator*. It's result is always correct, but sometimes unexpected, due to padding, or the belief that it is a magical array size determiner.

As an operator, the parentheses are not needed if acting in a variable.

```
 int foo;
 printf("%zu\n", sizeof foo);
```

is perfectly legal.

Comment: you should use `%zu` with `sizeof`, `%d` conversion specification with `sizeof` is undefined

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` with a structure type works as with any other type: the result of the operator is the size of the type in bytes. The size of the structure type is the same as the size of an object of this structure type.

The `sizeof` a structure object can be more than the size of the different elements of the structure types because of padding.

There can be padding of unspecified number of bytes after every structure member and the padding is taken into account in the size of the structure type (or of an object of the structure type)

To print the size of a structure type use the `z` conversion specifier in a `printf` format string:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof (struct my_structure_type));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read a little bit more about that:
http://somectips.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/what-is-the-size-of-struct/