# How to dynamically allocate memory for a struct with an unknown size?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

So I want to allocate memory for a struct but I am new to C and have no clue on how to allocate it. The struct of have consists of 2 ints, 1 char, 1 bool(could be changed to int), and 2 doubles. I am to read or input a file and store the information from that file into the struct but the amount of information from the file may change. So what would be the best way to create the necessary space for it?

Comment: How about `malloc`?

Comment: Don't worry. The compiler will know the size (and you can find out using the sizeof operator).

Comment: @Kerrek how do I malloc it? from what I know its malloc(sizeof(___) or like (int*)malloc(sizeof(___)). I have seen those but I am not sure how to use them.

Comment: @MickSharpe I am doing this for a class and the assignment requires it. How do I use the sizeof operator for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728377/how-the-sizeof-function-works-for-structures-in-c (sorry - don't how how to type links yet.)

Comment: @JMei In any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have ***2*** *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: ***(1)*** *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, ***(2)*** it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed. (and don't forget to `free` the memory you allocate, yes it is freed on exit, in all other circumstances -- it's up to you) Since you are learning C, I would recommend building good habits and accounting for and freeing all memory you allocate before the program exits.

Comment: Do you mean that the file might contain multiple records, each of which fits in one of these structs? (so you need to allocate space for many structs).  If not then I'm not sure what you mean by "the amount of information from the file may change".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `malloc` and `sizeof`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...

struct your_struct *s = malloc(sizeof(*s));
```

Comment: This must appear inside a function, it cannot appear at file scope as your answer shows.